# How to fix .. 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified

Tags: amazon-ses

1. My email has been successfully verified:

   [image: pic1]
2. But I cannot send the emails to others:

   > error : 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region US-EAST-1.

   [image: pic2]

Can you, please, help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 25):

Is this the first time you are using this account with SES? If so then you must be in sandbox mode

> If your account is still in the sandbox, you also must verify every
>   recipient email address except for the recipients provided by the
>   Amazon SES mailbox simulator.

[SES Doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/ses-errors.html)

You can follow these steps :

1. Log into the **AWS Management Console**.
2. Go to **SES Sending Limits Increase**.
3. Fill in the required details and set the **limit** to your desired usage

[Moving Out of Sandbox](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/request-production-access.html)

Comment: Glad it helped. Accept this answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: I'm not sure.It's a reminder that "Case Creation Severity : We’ve recently updated the names of case severity levels to make it easier for you to select the response time that best meets your needs." I do not understand what it means.

Comment: If you are having issues with requesting a limit raise then simply raise a "Support Ticket" with AWS and they will guide you through the process.

Comment: what is "Support Ticket".? how should i do.

Comment: Read the second Link, you will find your answer.

Comment: Anyone know how long this type of case typically takes to resolve?

Comment: They could've made it easier to find. Green checkmarks and "good to go!" all over the place, spent 15 minutes clicking until I finally found a screen that says "oh btw you're still in sandbox dude! so despite all of those wonderful green checkmarks and approvals nothing will actually work"

Answer (score 3):

You can only send emails **from** verified domains **to** verified domains and email addressed
In order to send to others, you must move your account **out of sandbox** mode by contacting AWS support and requesting it:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/console/ses/sandbox